# LoadRunner TruClient - How to measure page response time properly?

Tags: performance, load, loadrunner, truclient

Question for LoadRunner TruClient, how to measure page load time properly?

Right now I'm thinking the only way to do is to have 1) Click a link event 2) Verify object show up on the next page.

But if I put the transaction around 1)+2), the response time is really long. If I put the transaction around 2), the response time is really short. I feel it's not accurate measurement of page load time in both ways. What's the proper way to measure page load time? What should I set as the End Event for both steps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to measure client load on the front end the place to begin is in the developer tools long before you get to any sort of multi-user performance test, for any issue you find in the last 100 yards before deployment will have zero chance of going through the page architecture changes required to affect client performance

Example, from Google Chrome, developer tools

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I used developer tools to pick some of the elements that load really slow and put transaction after the action and around the wait for elements block to measure the transaction time.